# Is it possible to do an un-revert in svn?

Tags: svn, versions

I have mistakenly done an svn revert on the wrong directory and lost my last days worth of work. I think this is a long shot, but is there a way to do an "un revert" in svn?

Comment: Only if you reverted to a non-head revision.  Then you could recover the work that had been committed at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is any help, but I'm using TortoiseSVN on Windows myself, and there, files that are "Reverted" are moved to the Windows Recycle Bin, from which they can usually be recovered.

Reference: [TortoiseSVN Docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html)

Comment: I mis-tagged this question as TourtoiseSVN originally. I'm actually using Versions (on the mac). But, that's really good to know. Looks like Versions doesn't do the same thing though, because I don't see anything in the trash :(

Comment: Ouch, too bad :( It's slightly ironic that svn can do so much accidental damage, when you use it to *prevent* such damage in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, there is not a way to un-revert.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless windows saved a copy in the recycle bin like onnodb suggested.  If you never committed the changes you made, svn has no knowledge they ever existed.